# Regular expresssion in Notepad++, Remove a substring with an ending number

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file that contain binary and text data. These kind of string:

```
?^ ×ô\ ˜³^ <] Ï|] ci] Þí^ €K` ÙsZ ÑûZ øÔZ ÑûZ -\ æe^ Ÿ¯T dèZ €NT &ªP ÊY ¹–P èçO nßW ´X clQ ×ô\ WöV ­ V 4^ ˜³^ *$U ÊY S|R KS }PY ,£R ŒÄN ÑûZ GX íaT ?ŽX >S käP ñÛX 4R îàQ …ÈX ’½P ¢­O ¼‘W QýT ;T sY\ —7U QýT ¼V "¬U Î T VwY ;T "¬U óZV hæU ÃT ›±Y ¾U ÙvN >S ¦«J ,¦F CL bðG jhG ¦ÇµbH ibat3   uA  ¸  ô~  ô~ oð$GNTXT,01,01,00,txbuf alloc S*12
```

I would like to remove from this file all the text that contains the string: `$GNTXT`, and that ends with `S*12`.

I tried to use `(.*)GNTXT(.*)` but this selected all the lines and doesn't work.

Any idea?

Here i paste how is my string:
[image]

Comment: Try `^.*\$GNTXT.*S\h*\*\h*12$` See https://regex101.com/r/H8jBNO/1

Comment: Just FYI that editing a file with NPP that contains binary data might corrupt the file if it is not intended to be processed as a text file.

Comment: so is it not suggested to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Since the file contain binary data along with some text so it is suggested to copy the file before you open it using NPP.

As far as I have understood, you may apply this:

```
[^\s,;.:-]*\$GNTXT[^\s,;.:-]*|[^\s,;.:-]*S\*12(?=\s)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yp2Lur/1)

Explanation:

- `[^\s,;.:-]*` Any word beginning without `space, newline tab ,;.:-`
  shall be considered as part of word
- `\$GNTXT` It matches the word you have intended
- `[^\s,;.:-]*` Any word ending without `space, newline tab ,;.:-`
  shall be considered as part of word
- `|` alterative
- `[^\s,;.:-]*` Any word beginning without `space, newline tab ,;.:-`
  shall be considered as part of word
- `S\*12` It matches the word you have intended
- `(?=\s)` Positive lookahead to make sure that S*12 ends with newline/space/tab. You may include `,.;` if required here.

Comment: doesn't find any string using that regular expression

Comment: I just copied the text that you have provided and it worked in the demo link that I have provided. Need inspect what went wrong in your npp configuration. Let me know